# Can I pass a value from a button in a view to the controller using C# ASP.NET MVC and Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET MVC. I have an index page that pulls 3 random values from a database and displays them. I also have a button on that page that I want to randomize the returned values and display them. I have attempted putting a button into the view

```
<a href='@Url.Action("randButton","Home")' class="btn btn-primary">Randomize</a>
```

This approach is so close to giving me the desired result, but the problem is that, in production, when it redirects to the randButton page, I am able to refresh the page and all the randomization code fires again. I would like for it to randomize when the button is clicked, but not when the page is refreshed from the browser.

Index Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (checkDate())
        {
            setSelections();
        }

        FetchData();
        return View(restaurants);
    }

    public IActionResult randButton()
    {
        resetSelections();
        setSelections();
        FetchData();
        return View("Index", restaurants);
    }
```

I also tried copying the return value from index to randbutton.

I'll be happy to provide any further information required.

Comment: Do you specifically want the randomization *when the button is clicked*, or just *when the page is first loaded* and then the page re-uses those same values?  The former adds complexity that may be unnecessary here.  If the latter is fine, you'd just need to persist that data somewhere.  Session state seems reasonable in this case.

Comment: The functionality is such that when the page loads, it checks to see if a random set has been selected already today, if not, it does fire the randomization, otherwise, it just loads the view.  The purpose of the button is to manually randomize the set.  Currently, I have the data saved and updated in a sqlserver database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like the problem is that reloading the page re-invokes the `randButton()` action.  This is probably because of how that action is responding:

```
return View("Index", restaurants);
```

It's returning a view, which means the URL in the browser is to the `randButton()` action, which means reloading the page will re-invoke that action.

Separate commands from queries.  `Index` is a query (it doesn't modify data or state, it just displays it) and `randButton` is a command (it modifies data or state).

After performing the command, issue a re-direct to perform the query:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

So when the user clicks the button, they invoke the command and then the result of the command is a redirect response navigating them back to the `Index` to query the current state.  Then if they reload the page, they're just reloading the query.